# Is it possible to run Bitcoin-Client and Bitcoin-Full-Node on two different computers?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, full-node

I have my Bitcoin-Full-Node running on a Raspberry Pi4 hard wired on the home network.
Is it possible to install the Bitcoin-Client on another computer connected to the home network, but avoiding to install the full blockchain ? By doing this, my personal wallet would strictly be stored on my PC and I could initiate transactions from that PC.
Because the Pi4 running the Bitcoin-Full-Node would be ON 24/7, it would be the main server for information for the Bitcoin-Client.
I’m I understanding this properly ? I that feasible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bitcoin Core software only implements a fully-validating node. It has no other mode of operation, so it will always download, verify, and optionally store, all blocks. By running in pruning mode it is possible to only keep the last few 100 blocks on disk, but all earlier ones will still be downloaded and validated fully.

There are many other Bitcoin clients out there however, many of which are far more lightweight. Some of them can connect to a specified node of your choosing. Software recommendations are off-topic on this site, however.